# How to find on 'input' the value has the '//' ( forward slash ) more than one time consequently?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a path, where the user can use the `'/'` forward slash only one time. In case if he use more than one forward slash (`'//'`), I suppose to throw an error.. at present I am testing on key press like this:

```
this.validatePageName = function($input) {
    var val = $input.val().trim(),
              isValid = true;

    var forwardSlashes = !val.match('//');

    if (!forwardSlashes) {
        $input.denaliError( "\"" + val + "\"  is not valid for a page name.");
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
};
```

But apart from using 'match' - is there any good approach? any one suggest me some other bullet proof process if any?

Comment: You could run a loop from 0 .. val.length-2 and check if val.substring(i, 2) == '//'. But this is more code, will decrease readability, and will probably be slower because it has to be interpreted. So your match seems to be the best you can do.

Comment: why declare forwardSlashes at all? You can just do `if(val.match('//'))` for better readability and no need for 2 negations(!).

Comment: You could also use `test()` : `/\/\//.test(val) -> boolean`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(val.indexOf("//") > -1){
```

This is what I was taught to use, however using `match` is perfectly fine too.